# User can edit paragraph of html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Well, I have some paragraphs in my php that is coming from a database, and I want the user to have the ability to double click the text or press a button, edit the text, and then save it in database. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. But a detailed answer on how to do that exactly is too broad for SO. You should probably start with javascript to convert your texts to `textareas` on click events or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was just looking for a clue to start googling.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but where are you stuck? The JavaScript to enable the editing, or the means by which the edited text/HTML should be stored back into the database? Both? And if it's 'both' then you've got (potentially) two questions rather than one.

Comment: Note that for a richer inteface you can also use `contenteditable` and Ajax, in stead of a `textarea` and classic `submit`. Have a look at this: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: Both of this David, but now it's starting to get clearer with all the answers. I think I can make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.
All you need to do is put a submit button that whenever it is clicked you preview a textarea. Then you show the value from the database on the textarea (by SELECT on the SQL command) and then after the 'send' submit button (after the user finished editing) take the value the user wrote by the name of the textarea and put it instead of the text you previewed (INSERT INTO command).

Comment: would that not be UPDATE in stead of INSERT? The user is editing, not creating

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I'm starting to understand the way I have to make it.

Comment: No that I know. As I know and use it as the INSERT INTO function. Maybe there is an option to use the UPDATE one.
I'm glad I helped (:

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a textarea by setting the contentEditable property to true or false on the element that contain the text.

For example, if the HTML is like :

```
<p id="sometext">This is the paragraph you cant to be able to edit</p>
```

You can use `document.getElementById("sometext").contentEditable = true;` in JS to make it editable - and `document.getElementById("sometext").contentEditable = false;` to reverse it.

Then you could for example retrieve the innerHTML of the element when done with editing, and send it via AJAX to a PHP processing page (updating into MySQL DB) ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You'd need a textarea with submit button, and then you would take the contents of the textarea and use SQL update to update the database with the contents of the textarea.

A full answer is a tad to broad for Stack Overflow.